# how to remove optional from string i have used following code

Tags: ios, swift3

```
 class func shareString(title : String, array: [AnyObject]) -> String {

        var strValue: String!

        //strValue = "\(title)"

        for i in 0...array.count-1 {

            let share:[String: String?] = array[i] as! [String : String?]
            strValue = "\n\n \(strValue),   \n\n \(share["title"])  \n\n\(share["value"])"
        }

        return strValue!

    }



//Optional("\n\n Optional(\"\\n\\n nil,   \\n\\n Optional(Optional(\\\"\\\\n LayFlat\\\"))  \\n\\nOptional(Optional(\\\"252.0\\\"))\"),   \n\n Optional(Optional(\"\\n  Die Diameter\"))  \n\nOptional(Optional(\"25.0\"))"),   

 Optional(Optional("\n Output"))  

Optional(Optional("6.42096"))
```

Comment: you need use if let or guard let for remove optional

Comment: use if let share:[String: String?] = array[i] as! [String : String?]{.....}

Comment: i simply used ! and my problem is solved           class func shareString(title : String!, array: [AnyObject]) -> String {
        
        var strValue: String!
        
        strValue = "\(title!)"
        if array.count > 0 {
            for i in 0...array.count-1 {
                
                let share:[String: String] = array[i] as! [String : String]
                strValue = "\n\n\(strValue!)   \(share["title"]!)  \(share["value"]!)"
            }

        }
        
        return strValue!
        
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subscript it will already return optional and you are setting dictionary with value `String?` means you are getting optional twice also specifying array of AnyObject make it array of `[[String:String]]` so no need to cast it letter again. Also initialized the `strValue` with empty string.

```
var strValue = ""
if let dicArray = array as? [[String:String]] {
    for dic in dicArray {
        if let title = dic["title"], let value = dic["value"] {
            strValue += "\n\n \(title)  \n\n\(value)"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use optional chaining like bellow

   > strValue = "\n\n (strValue ?? ""),   \n\n (share["title"] ?? "") 
   >   \n\n(share["value"] ?? "")"
2. Use force unwrap variable if it has value

   > strValue = "\n\n (strValue!),   \n\n (share["title"]!) 
   >   \n\n(share["value"]!)"

Comment: `strValue!` will crash as of OP haven't initialized the  strValue

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in 0...array.count-1 {

    let share:[String: String?] = array[i] as! [String : String?]

    if let title = share["title"], let value = share["value"]{
        print("title: \(title) , Value: \(value)")
        //output: title: 252.0 , Value: Die Diameter
    }
}
```

Comment: `title` and `value` are still `optionals` because type of dictionary is `[String : String?]` means value is optional so you need to wrapped optional twice

Comment: You should use the correct swift pattern, so for example use for a in array{
...... if let elem as? [String : String?] {..